# Rbenv and Rails mismatches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

Good morning everyone,
I've installed Ruby 3.0.2 via rbenv in order to test-drive a Rails 6.0 app. It seems like rbenv's Rails shiv is not working properly.

```
$ rbenv install 3.0.2
Downloading ruby-3.0.2.tar.gz...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/3.0/ruby-3.0.2.tar.gz
Installing ruby-3.0.2...
Installed ruby-3.0.2 to /home/bjpcjp/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2

(working):~/datadrive/projects/ruby-rails/rails6ruby3/demo2$ ruby -v
ruby 3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233) [x86_64-linux]

(working):~/datadrive/projects/ruby-rails/rails6ruby3/demo2$ rails s
Your Ruby version is 2.7.2, but your Gemfile specified 3.0.2
```

There's no .ruby-version in my home path; .ruby-version in my local path is 3.0.2.

Eventually I used `$rbenv shell 3.0.2` to get rails running on the correct executable.

This seems really counterintuitive. Any `rbenv` best practices out there?

Comment: If you have rbenv you don't need to specify ruby version in the Gemfile

Comment: try running `bundle exec rails s`?